# Как сделать блок схему задачи с координатами ? Ввод и тд

Tags: блок-схема, псевдокод

Нужно сделать блок схему задачи, условие: нужно место откуда вы будете идти - грубо говоря, в другую точку, при этом добавив по пути сложности (пример, из дома в школу, но при этом надо сесть на автобус, или совершить 2 пересадки)

Ниже пример условия

> 1. Подъем на эверест
>
> 1.1 Определить ориентацию в пространстве
>
> 1.2 Построение маршрута
>
> 1.3 Вызов функцию ходить
>
> 1.4 Вызвать пункт 1.1, вызвать пункт 1.2 если 1.2 = 1.1, то завершаем

Comment: с каким именно пунктом возникли сложности? Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: В принципе, создать блок схему надо, но я даже понятия не имею, как её создать с алгоритмом перемещения по координатам, и как их ввести

Comment: в блок-схеме не надо ничего вводить. Просто показываешь блоками что происходит